# Hibernate JPA - How to obtain Path to property of class mapped on single column?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, custom-type

I'm using JPA. I have java entity class with specyfic property - class that is mapped on single column:

```
@Entity
MyClass{

    @Column(length = 6, nullable = true)
    @Type(type = "mypackage.MyInnerClassHibernateType")
    @Mergable
    private MyInnerClass myProperty;

    ...

}
```

Class MyInnerClass is simple contain only one String and few methods:

```
public class MyInnerClass{

    private String value;

    ...
}
```

I have problem with building criteria. Assume that I have Join<?,MyClass> jMyClass,
and I need Path<String> to value, so I can compare it using builder.like(...).

How to do it?

```
Path<String> path = jMyClass.get("myProperty");
```

gives me: *Parameter value did not match expected type* and

```
Path<String> path = jMyClass.get("myProperty").get("value");
```

gives me: *Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null]*

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done, because in the end it will we SQL query that is run against database. Database is not aware of the fact that data stored to the `myProperty` is object with field named `value`.

In general also other constructs of Java programming language cannot be used in SQL queries - not even if query is constructed via Criteria API.